# Validate multiple related objects through foreign key field in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

In the example shown by the code below, is it possible to automatically validate and create instances of `Endereco` and `Coordenada` using `LocalizacaoForm`?

The reason why I want to do this is so that I can use Generic Views as much as possible, and they don't work well (at least not out-of-the-box) with more than one ModelForm per view.

In the application, I want to render a `LocalizacaoForm` and show the fields from `Endereco` and `Coordenada` as well. What I am doing in so far doesn't seem to solve it, because `self.fields.update(fields_for_model(Coordenada))` only creates the input fields, not an actual instance of `Coordenada`. Therefore I get a `django NOT NULL constraint failed id` for the object *coordenada*.

Is there a way to do what I want or should I just stick with rendering each form separately?

```
#models.py
class Coordenada(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    altitude = models.FloatField()
    erro_horizontal = models.FloatField()

class Endereco(models.Model):
    cep = models.IntegerField()
    uf = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    localidade = models.CharField(max_length=50)  # nome da cidade
    # other fields...

class Localizacao(models.Model):
    endereco = models.OneToOneField(Endereco)
    coordenada_geografica = models.ForeignKey('Coordenada')

#forms.py
class LocalizacaoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LocalizacaoForm, self).__init__(instance=instance, *args, **kwargs)
        # Retrieve the fields from Endereco and Coordenada model and update the fields with it
        self.fields.update(fields_for_model(Endereco))
        self.fields.update(fields_for_model(Coordenada))

    class Meta:
        model = Localizacao
        exclude = ('endereco', 'coordenada_geografica')

#views.py
class LocalizacaoCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Localizacao
    form_class = LocalizacaoForm
    template_name = 'localizacao_create_form.html'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create instances of `Coordenada` and `Endereco` in the `save()` method of `LocalizacaoForm`, like this:

```
class LocalizacaoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # The rest of the form ...
    # ...

    def save(self, commit=False):
        localizacao = super(LocalizacaoForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # create an instance of Coordenada
        coordenada = Coordenada.objects.create(
                        latitude=self.cleaned_data['latitude'],
                        longitude=self.cleaned_data['longitude'],
                        altitude=self.cleaned_data['altitude'],
                        erro_horizontal=self.cleaned_data['erro_horizontal']
                    )

        # create an instance of Endereco
        endereco = Endereco.objects.create(
                        cep=self.cleaned_data['cep'],
                        uf=self.cleaned_data['uf'],
                        localidade=self.cleaned_data['localidade'],
                    )

        # add those instances to localizacao
        localizacao.coordenada_geografica = coordenada
        localizacao.endereco = endereco

        if commit:
            localizacao.save()
        return localizacao
```

Comment: Works like a charm and looks much cleaner than if I had created the each form separately. 
Thanks!